# awk: change a field's value conditionally based on the value of another column

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, conditional-statements, text-processing

I have a table `snp150Common.txt`, where the second and third fields `$2 and $3` can be equal or not.

If they are equal, I want `$2` to become `$2-1`, so that:

```
chr1    10177   10177   rs367896724 -   -   -/C insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    10352   10352   rs555500075 -   -   -/A insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    11007   11008   rs575272151 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    11011   11012   rs544419019 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    13109   13110   rs540538026 G   G   A/G single      intron
chr1    13115   13116   rs62635286  T   T   G/T single      intron
chr1    13117   13118   rs62028691  A   A   C/T single      intron
chr1    13272   13273   rs531730856 G   G   C/G single      ncRNA
chr1    14463   14464   rs546169444 A   A   A/T single      near-gene-3,ncRNA
```

becomes:

```
chr1    10176   10177   rs367896724 -   -   -/C insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    10351   10352   rs555500075 -   -   -/A insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    11007   11008   rs575272151 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    11011   11012   rs544419019 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    13109   13110   rs540538026 G   G   A/G single      intron
chr1    13115   13116   rs62635286  T   T   G/T single      intron
chr1    13117   13118   rs62028691  A   A   C/T single      intron
chr1    13272   13273   rs531730856 G   G   C/G single      ncRNA
chr1    14463   14464   rs546169444 A   A   A/T single      near-gene-3,ncRNA
```

My current command adapted from https://askubuntu.com/a/312843:

```
zcat < snp150/snp150Common.txt.gz | head | awk '{ if ($2 == $3) $2=$2-1; print $0 }' | cut -f 2,3,4,5,8,9,10,12,16
```

gives the same output:

```
chr1    10177   10177   rs367896724 -   -   -/C insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    10352   10352   rs555500075 -   -   -/A insertion   near-gene-5
chr1    11007   11008   rs575272151 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    11011   11012   rs544419019 C   C   C/G single      near-gene-5
chr1    13109   13110   rs540538026 G   G   A/G single      intron
chr1    13115   13116   rs62635286  T   T   G/T single      intron
chr1    13117   13118   rs62028691  A   A   C/T single      intron
chr1    13272   13273   rs531730856 G   G   C/G single      ncRNA
chr1    14463   14464   rs546169444 A   A   A/T single      near-gene-3,ncRNA
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `cut` (which is pretty foo as you are already using awk) indicates that the `snp150Common.txt` has more columns than you show above. Are you sure `$2` and `$3` are the columns you really want to compare?

Comment: And *that* is why I suck at programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on pure speculation of the source file format:

```
$ zcat snp150/snp150Common.txt.gz | 
  awk '
  BEGIN { OFS="\t" }                       # field separators are most likely tabs
  {
      if ($3 == $4)                        # based on cut these should be compared
          $3=$3-1
      print $2,$3,$4,$5,$8,$9,$10,$12,$16  # ... and there fields printed
  }
  NR==10 { exit }'                         # this replaces head
```

And remember: Practising (anything but sucking) makes you suck less.